# How to push an array of objects in Firebase Firestore?

Tags: arrays, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I need to add the following cars[] array of object into the Firestore document .

```
vendor:"XYZ broker",
phone:xxx-xxx-xxxx,
cars=[
{
model:Hyunday,
year:2021
},
{
model:BMW,
year:2018
}
]
```

I know I can append a new object to the array by using `arrayUnion`, but the issue is that cars[] array may not exists initially(upon document creation), so the idea is to append data to the cars[] (if cars[] exists) or create a new cars[] array with the data (if cars[] don't exists). Is this possible to do with GCP? The documentation I've read discussed only appending/removing data from the existing array, but not how to check if array exists initially. Any advise is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`arrayUnion()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data?hl=en&authuser=0#update_elements_in_an_array) with the [`setDoc()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data?hl=en&authuser=0#set_a_document) method and `merge` option the same way you would use it with the `updateDoc()` method, in such a way that:

- If the doc does not exists it will be created with the array
- If the doc exists and the array does not exists, the array will be created
- If the doc exists and the array exists, the objects in the array passed to the `arrayUnion()` method will be added to the document's array (**if** they are not already in the document's array)

---

For example with the JS SDK:

```js
import { doc, setDoc, arrayUnion } from "firebase/firestore";

const theRef = doc(db, "foo", "bar");

await setDoc(
  theRef,
  {
    vendor: "XYZ broker",
    phone: "xxx-xxx-xxxx",
    cars: arrayUnion(
      ...[   // <=== Note the spread operator
        {
          model: "Hyunday",
          year: 2021,
        },
        {
          model: "BMW",
          year: 2018,
        },
      ]
    ),
  },
  { merge: true }
);
```

---

More details on the spread operator/syntax [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).